# How to call one pipeline script from another in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I wish to understand how we can call one pipeline script from another in Jenkins? As of now, i am trying the below code and it is throwing **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run**.

My requirement is pretty straightforward, i wish to call separate scripts based on the environment.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
  
    stage('DEPLOYMENT STARTED') {
      when {
        expression {
          ENV_DEPLOY == 'DEVELOPMENT'
        }
      }
      steps {
        script {
            load 'Java/MyApp/build/build_my_app_jenkins
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: My guess based on the error message is that your `Java/MyApp/build/build_my_app_jenkins` script has a `pipeline { }` block inside it, thus making this have a pipeline nested in another pipeline causing that error.

I think you mean to just load the particular steps from the script and not the entire pipeline itself, so maybe the steps just need to be extracted into their own file?

Comment: Have you considered moving your script to Shared Libraries? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following code:

```
node() {
  if(ENV_DEPLOY == 'DEVELOPMENT'){
    def buildModule = load 'Java/MyApp/build/build_my_app_jenkins'
    buildModule.someBuildFunction()
  }
}
```

This should work even if you have `pipeline` inside your function

Comment: It worked, thank you. However, a little additional information, the second script(build_my_app_jenkins) shouldn't contain any blocks such as stage, steps, script. Just the raw commands, everything else should be part of the original script.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger second Jenkins job from the first one you need to run:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'ANY_LABEL_HERE'
  }
  stages {
    stage('trigger downstream job') {
      steps {
        build job: 'NAME_OF_THE_SECOND_JOB'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: here it is not exactly a configured job but a pipeline script which is kept in the same location as that of the main script.